# Is there a way to split my tests and have them run parallel in my lerna monorepo?

Tags: continuous-integration, circleci

I have a lerna monorepo with this sort of structure:

```
packages
  - package1
    - src
      - components
        - component1
          - component1.test.js
  - package2
  - package3
  - package4
package.json
```

In my root `package.json`, my test script looks like this:

```js
"scripts": {
    "test": "lerna run --stream test",
 },
```

and in my individual `package.json`s they're being run with a test command of

```js
"scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
},
```

And with my `config.yml`, I'm running my test job like so:

```
jobs:
  test:
    <<: *defaults
    steps:
      - attach_workspace:
          at: ~/

      # run tests!
      - run: yarn test 
      # will run lerna run --stream test
```

Currently, when I run my tests, I run them all at once using `lerna run --stream test -- --runInBand` which will run **all** the tests in each package **all at once**. This poses some problems, most notably that circleci will error with **error 137: Out of memory**.

A workaround is to just pay for a bigger plan have change our `resource_class` to `medium+`, but I feel like that's a bit overkill.

I was thinking of alternatives and happened upon [parallelism](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/parallelism-faster-jobs/). I'm very new to circle, so I'm wondering if it's possible to split my tests by package and run them parallel to each other?

I've tried something like adding `parallelism: 4` to my test job, but it runs **all** the tests 4 times. Is it possible to do something like this? Or should I just have a separate job and `cd` into each package and run `yarn test` individually?

Comment: I found myself in a similar situation, also wanting to elegantly combine CircleCI's `parallelism` feature with `lerna run`. I opened this feature request for native support: https://github.com/lerna/lerna/issues/2632

Answer (score -1):

We wrote our own little extension to do this: [`lerna-parallelism`](https://github.com/ClarkSource/lerna-parallelism)

It integrates automatically with CircleCI's `parallelism` env variables.